# Скажите можно ли сказать,что это исправление сделает мой код более DRY?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Читаю учебник MOZILLA по джанго(скорее туториал).Там есть пример валидации даты (просрочена или нет):

```
@property
def is_overdue(self):
    if self.due_back and date.today() > self.due_back:
        return True
    return False
```

Но мне прямо таки хочется исправить на:

```
 @property
    def is_overdue(self):
        if date.today() => self.due_back:
            return True
        return False
```

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: Собственно чуть ниже кода написано примечание:

Comment: Примечание. Сначала мы проверим, является ли due_back пустым, прежде чем проводить сравнение. Пустое поле due_back заставило Django выкидывать ошибку, а не показывать страницу: пустые значения не сопоставимы. Это не то, что мы хотели бы, чтобы наши пользователи испытывали!

Comment: "if self.due_back" это проверка на то, что значение self.due_back не пустое и уже только после этого выполняется сравнение.

Comment: Спасибо Большое

Comment: @Omerta Omerta Не являются ли они семантически разными, если  self.due_back выдает в условии false? То есть что эти функции возвращают в этом случае?

Comment: Кажется, правильнее всего будет `return bool(self.due_back is not None and date.today() > self.due_back)`

Comment: (хотя если я написал is not None, то bool() не нужен)

Comment: Правильнее всего это так, как написано. В выражении `if self.due_back` атрибут self.due_back приводится к булеву значению. Это значит, что `None`, `False`, пустая строка, 0 и прочие пустые значения будут приведены к значению `False` и сравнение с `date.today()` не выполнится, потому что сравнивать не с чем. Подробнее о приведении типов можно посмотреть здесь [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)